# How to encode Internet address

Tags: java, email, mime-message

code to send email is following:

```
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setSubject("subject", "UTF-8"); // here you specify your subject encoding
    msg.setContent("yourBody", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

    msg.setFrom("senderAddress");
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(address));
    Transport.send(msg);
```

My probelem is that as as i have  encoded subject in utf-8 how can i encode recipient address ie. `new InternetAddress(address)`

Comment: Why would you encode recipient address ?

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue: Since mail is in foreign language so as recipient address

Comment: @Romi: where are you getting your email address(s) from? database or some property file? is `address` a `String`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Email address should follow RFC822 standard

JavaMail's MimeMessage uses [InternetAddress](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html):

> This class represents an Internet email address using the syntax of
>   RFC822. Typical address syntax is of the form "user@host.domain" or
>   "Personal Name < user@host.domain >".

[RFC822 format](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/rfc/822addr.html) says:

> Note that RFC 822 limits the character repertoire to [ASCII](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars.html#ascii). In
>   practice, other characters (such as ä or é) usually work inside quoted
>   strings used for commenting purposes (and comments), but they must not
>   be used in addresses proper.

## Personal names for address supports different charsets

InternetAddress uses a personal name:

> If the name contains non US-ASCII characters,
>   then the name will be encoded using the specified charset as per RFC
>   2047. If the name contains only US-ASCII characters, no encoding is done and the name is used as is.

To set charset for encoding, there is a [InternetAddress#constructor](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html). Looking at sources:

```
public InternetAddress(String address, String personal, String charset)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    this.address = address;
    setPersonal(personal, charset);
}
```

it just calls [setPersonal(..)](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html), thus choose the way which is the most convenient for you.

To lookup a charset, use [Charset.forName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: what is personal, i have special char in address that is not displaying correctly

Comment: @Romi personal name is a name for email address, for example: **"Евгений Мельник" <zen@melnik.lt>**, where first part is name and second part is address.

Answer (score 4):

I do this, where addressString is an email address with NLS characters:

```
InternetAddress address = new InternetAddress(addressString);
String personal = address.getPersonal();
if(personal != null) {
  address.setPersonal(personal, "utf-8");
}
```

`getPersonal()` gets the raw personal name if there is one, because if you constructed the InternetAddress with a single string, or using `InternetAddress.parse()`, you won't have the personal name part in a separate string:

> public java.lang.String getPersonal()
>
> Get the personal name. If the name is encoded as per RFC 2047, it is decoded and converted into Unicode. If the decoding or conversion fails, the raw data is returned as is.

Then `setPersonal()` sets the string back again but this time telling `InternetAddress` to encode it:

> public void setPersonal(java.lang.String name, java.lang.String charset)
>
> Set the personal name. If the name contains non US-ASCII characters, then the name will be encoded using the specified charset as per RFC 2047. If the name contains only US-ASCII characters, no encoding is done and the name is used as is.