# How can I send email to unicode email recipient through java mail

Tags: spring, email, unicode, internationalization, jakarta-mail

How can I send email to email address like महाराजा@test.com? I am using spring and java mail for sending emails. I get exception javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Local address contains control or whitespace in string while sending the email.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encode Internet address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830770/how-to-encode-internet-address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately javax.mail does not yet support the RFC 653x family of standards that enables internationalised e-mail addresses. [Bug tracker](https://kenai.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6216)

Actually right now very little internet mail infrastructure supports it, so you're probably not missing much, yet.

Comment: Thanks for your comment it clears lot of things. I tried turning of strict encoding and adding quotes to email address as mentioned in first comment and error changed to SMTPAddressFailedException: 501 5.5.4 Invalid Address. to summarize isn't there any way to support sending mail to i18n address?